# ¿Que es ''modular'' un proyecto?

Tags: browserify, modular

Estoy aprendiendo de tecnologias en Frontend y estoy aprendiendo a usar Browserify y me tope con que usaban la definición ''modular'' con Browserify. Espero alguien me pueda decir que significa modular y para que sirve. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Perdon mi pregunta, estas aprendiendo desde cero, sin tener conocimiento, o ya tienes conocimiento previo, te hago esa pregunta, ya que hablas de **Browserify**, y creo que es como un framework o algo asi

Comment: Tengo conocimiento de html, css y js, pero en cuanto a browserify no tengo ningun conocimiento

Comment: Bueno no he trabajado con eso, pero cuando hablas de algo modular, es que tenga la facilidad de crear un proyecto mediante módulos, por ejemplo, cuando tienes fichas de legos y creas un personaje, lo creas mediante módulos, utilizas los necesarios para crear algo, lo mismo en programación, separas responsabilidades a través de módulos, es una buena practica a la hora de desarrollar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta es una pregunta bastante abstracta y no hay una respuesta precisa en el escenario javascript global. Lo que es o no es un módulo tiene al menos tres interpretaciones (tres y media contando UMD) pero voy a responderte en un plano general.

Cuando usas una librería JS, ésta puede tener requerimientos o dependencias. Por ejemplo, cuando usas bootstrap, depende de jQuery, así que lo indicado es poner la etiqueta script de jquery antes que la etiqueta script de bootstrap.

Esas dependencias pueden tener un nivel de anidación muy rebuscado, tal que no se puede resolver meramente ordenando las etiquetas script. Puede darse por ejemplo que

```
- Datatables Bootstrap depende de
  - DataTables que depende de
    - jQuery
  - Bootstrap que depende de
    - jQuery
```

Ese árbol de dependencias es trivial de resolver en Node.js, porque todo está en su sistema local y lo cargas cuando montas la aplicación. En el browser, en cambio, tienes que elegir entre:

- requerir un millón de scripts sin control real sobre la jerarquía de dependencias
- usar un sistema asíncrono como Require.js o [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) y cargas las dependencias a medida que son requeridas (con la latencia que ello acarrea)
- concatenar en un **módulo** los puntos de entrada de las librerías que necesitas.

Browserify cumple con la tercera opción. Concatena en un solo archivo todas las dependencias de lo que quieres usar, conociendo sólo el último tramo. Dado que la librería que quieres usar declare sus dependencias

```
var DataTables=require('DataTables');
```

Y sus dependencias declaren sus dependencias, y así sucesivamente, browserify se encarga de construir un módulo que incluya todos los requerimientos anidados de la librería final que quieres utilizar.

Browserify saltó a la fama hace unos 5 años y sigue siendo ultra popular, pero hoy existen otras librerías (Webpack, JSPM) que cumplen una labor similar resolviendo el *pero* de browserify que es que dos librerías browserificadas pueden tener una dependencia en común (por ejemplo jQuery) y en cada una viene jQuery de regalo, adosado.